# How to resize a 2D matrix in python corresponding to pixellation effect on image

Tags: python, arrays

Hi please dont downvote as I really couldnt find it and am posting it here after searching it.

I have an array which is 200X500 (ie 100000 elements). Each of the element has two values stored in a tuple.

```
[[ (20,2), (30,40)....],
 [ (10,2), (10,20)....],
 [....................],
 [....................],
 [....................]]
```

I want to convert this array to 100X250. Thus each element now will have average values of 2X2 subgrids from above array. So for example now in this 2x2 subgrid grid from above matrix

```
(20,2),(30,40),
(10,2),(10,20)
```

will become single element as
(20+30+10+10)/4 = 17.5
((2+40+2+20)/4  = 16

```
(17.5,16)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `row` and `col` as the indices for the large matrix which I call `mat`. Here is a way to do the averaging using a list comprehension. This can be done more simply and more slowly using two nested `for` loops. This code does no error checking--it assumes `mat` is really a rectangular matrix with an even number of rows and of columns with each entry a 2-tuple of numbers. Real code should have error checking, which I'll leave to you.

```
avg = [[
        (
            ( mat[row][col][0]
            + mat[row][col+1][0]
            + mat[row+1][col][0]
            + mat[row+1][col+1][0] ) / 4.0
        , 
            ( mat[row][col][1]
            + mat[row][col+1][1]
            + mat[row+1][col][1]
            + mat[row+1][col+1][1] ) / 4.0
        )
        for col in range(0, len(mat[0]), 2) ]
    for row in range(0, len(mat), 2)
]
```

The first `range()` executed (the second in the text) sets the `row` index to every other row, and the other does every other column. The item `mat[row][col][0]` takes the 0th (usually called first) item in the tuple at location `row` and `col`. Adding `1` to `row` or `col` gets the next row or column, and replacing the `[0]` with `[1]` gets the other item in the tuple.

Using an example similar to yours,

```
mat = [[(20,2), (30,40), (0,0), (0,0)],
       [(10,2), (10,20), (0,0), (0,0)],
       [(10,2), (10,40), (1,1), (1,1)],
       [(10,2), (10,20), (1,1), (1,1)]]
```

yields the result for `for r in avg: print(r)`

```
[(17.5, 16.0), (0.0, 0.0)]
[(10.0, 16.0), (1.0, 1.0)]
```

Is that clear?

Comment: Hi ran your code on `mat=np.random.rand(200,500,2)`, but got output avg as list of length 25000. How can I reshape it preserve consistency with respect to original matrix `mat`

Comment: @Sunita: Oops, I have edited my answer to get a resulting rectangular matrix.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Sir can you help me with this problem (its similar to the one you are tried solving , I think you can help me out quickly) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211032/how-to-interpolate-excel-file-of-unordered-coordinates-to-a-grid

Answer (score 0):

You can add each adjacent 2 rows and 2 columns then the array converts from 200*500 to 100*250.Now you can calculate the average.

Comment: Thanks but how do I perform this indexing and averaging. Could you pls help

Comment: import numpy as np

t=np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 4,  9, 14, 16]])

m,n=t.shape
a=np.zeros((int(m/2),int(n)))
for i in range(0,len(t),2):
 a[int(i/2)]=t[i]+t[i+1]

s=a.T
b=np.zeros((int(m/2),int(n/2)))
for i in range(0,len(s),2):
 b[int(i/2)]=s[i]+s[i+1]

b=b.T
b=b/4
print(b)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It handles window size larger than 2 and handles if the window size does not evenly divide the source array dimensions.

```
rows = 200
cols = 500
window_size = 2
for i in range(0,int(rows/window_size)):
    for j in range(0,int(cols/window_size)):
        elem1_sum = 0.0
        elem2_sum = 0.0
        total_elems = 0.0
        for ii in range(0,window_size):
            for jj in range(0,window_size):
                source_row_index = i*window_size + ii
                source_col_index = j*window_size + jj
                if source_row_index >= rows or source_col_index >= cols:
                    continue
                elem1_sum += source_arr[source_row_index][source_col_index][0]
                elem2_sum += source_arr[source_row_index][source_col_index][1]
                total_elems += 1.0
        dest_arr[i][j][0] = elem1_sum/total_elems
        dest_arr[i][j][1] = elem2_sum/total_elems
```

EDIT: Allocate source_arr and dest_arr as:

```
  source_arr=np.random.rand(rows,cols,2)
  dest_arr=np.zeros(shape=(rows/window_size,cols/window_size,2))
```