# How to interpolate Excel file of unordered coordinates to a grid

Tags: python, arrays, interpolation

I have csv files which are 1200 Rows x 3 Columns. Number of rows can differ from as low as 500 to as large as 5000 but columns remain same.

I want to create a feature vector from these files which will thus maintain consistent cells/vector length & thus help in finding out the distance between these vectors.

```
 FILE_1
 A, B, C
 (267.09669678867186, 6.3664069175720197, 1257325.5809999991),
 (368.24070923984374, 9.0808353424072301, 49603.662999999884),
 (324.21470826328124, 11.489830970764199, 244391.04699999979),
 (514.33452027500005, 7.5162401199340803, 56322.424999999988),
 (386.19673340976561, 9.4927110671997106, 175958.77100000033),
 (240.09965330898439, 10.3463039398193, 457819.8519411764),
 (242.17559998691405, 8.4401674270629901, 144891.51100000029),
 (314.23066895664061, 7.4405002593994096, 58433.818999999959),
 (933.3073596304688, 7.1564397811889604, 41977.960000000014),
 (274.04136473476564, 4.8482465744018599, 48782.314891525479),
 (584.2639294320312, 7.90128517150879, 49730.705000000096),
 (202.13173096835936, 10.559995651245099, 20847.805144088608),
 (324.98563963710939, 2.2546300888061501, 43767.774800000007),
 (464.35059935390626, 11.573680877685501, 1701597.3915132943),
 (776.28339964687495, 8.7755222320556605, 106882.2469999999),
 (310.11652952968751, 10.3175926208496, 710341.19162800116),
 (331.19962889492189, 10.7578010559082, 224621.80632433048),
 (452.31337752387947, 7.3100395202636701, 820707.26700000139),
 (430.16615111171876, 10.134071350097701, 18197.691999999963),
 (498.24687010585939, 11.0102319717407, 45423.269964585743),
   .....,
   .....,
   500th row

 FILE_2
 (363.02781861484374, 8.8369808197021502, 72898.479666666608),
(644.20353882968755, 8.6263589859008807, 22776.78799999999),
(259.25105469882811, 9.8575859069824201, 499615.64068339905),
(410.19474608242189, 9.8795070648193395, 316146.18800000293),
(288.12153809726561, 4.7451887130737296, 58615.577999999943),
(376.25868409335936, 10.508985519409199, 196522.12200000012),
(261.11118895351564, 8.5228433609008807, 32721.110000000026),
(319.98896605312501, 3.2100667953491202, 60587.077000000027),
(286.94926268398439, 4.7687568664550799, 47842.133999999867),
(121.00206177890625, 7.9372291564941397, 239813.20531182736),
(308.19895750820314, 6.0029039382934597, 26354.519000000011),
(677.17011839687495, 9.0299625396728498, 10391.757655172449),
(182.1304913216797, 8.0010566711425799, 145583.55700000061),
(187.06341736972655, 9.9460496902465803, 77488.229000000007),
(144.07867615878905, 3.6044106483459499, 104651.56499999999),
(288.92317015468751, 4.3750333786010698, 151872.1949999998),
(228.2089825326172, 4.4475774765014604, 658120.07628214348),
(496.18831055820311, 11.422966003418001, 2371155.6659999997),
(467.30134398281251, 11.0771179199219, 109702.48440899582),
(163.08418089687501, 5.7271881103515598, 38107.106791666629),
   .....,
   .....,
   3400th row
```

You can see that there is no correspondence between the two files, i.e. if someone asked you to calculate the distance between these two vectors its not possible.

The aim is to be able to interpolate the rows of both the files in such a manner so that there is a consistency across all such files. i.e. when I look up first row,
it should represent same feature across all the files. Now lest look at FILE_1

```
Range of values for three columns is (considering only 20 rows for time being)

A: 202.13173096835936,933.3073596304688

B: 2.2546300888061501, 11.573680877685501

C: 18197.691999999963,1701597.3915132943
```

I want to put these points on a 3d array, the grid size of which will be .1X.1X.1 (or lets say 10X10X10 or any arbitrary size grid cell) 
    But for that to work we need to normalize the data (mean normalize etc)

Now the data we have is a 3d data, which need to be normalized in order to interpolate them into this 3d array. Which neednt be 3d even if its a vector then that will also do.

Now when I said I need to average the points, by that I meant that if in a cell more than two points happen to fall (which will happen if the cell size is big eg 100X100X100) then we will take the average value of x,y,z coordinate as the value of that cell.

These interpolated vectors will have same length & correspondence, because corresponding point of a vector when compared to rest of such vectors will represent same point.

**NOTE : Min & Max range for all coordinates across all files is 100:1000,2:12, 10000:2000000

Comment: Can anyone pls help !! :-(

Comment: Column A, second row of your sample data starts `3,934,`. Is that supposed to be `3.934,`? How do you get that data from Excel into Python? In point 1, is that grid to be in Excel or in a Python 2D list or something else? In your point 2, what does "I'd just keep the average values of each of the coordinate" mean? And what if you do not "keep" them? Just what output overall do you want?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Sir Ive added better explanation I hope that helps.

Comment: Can you define "normalize", "interpolate", "feature vector", "distance" ? What is the semantic of a file, i.e why not considering all records as a whole ?

Comment: @Setop Suppose I give you two random distributions of 3d coordinates. "Interpolation" : Now suppose you draw a 2x2 grid (4 cells) across these two distributions and for each cell you take average value of all points falling in this cell, then you have a vector which is 1x4 for both the distributions. You can now simply calculate the distance between these two 1x4 vectors (eg by using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). Why you need to normalize (not necessary) is because the range of values varies massively across the three coordinates.